# Given a point in 3D space and a direction Vector, find the point where y = 8

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a Vector `(5.3, 1, 2.3)` and I want to move it using a normalized Vector with direction `(-0.5, 0.7, -0.5)` until such a point in which `y = 8`

The equation kind of looks like this (I'm sure this isn't the right way to write this)

`(5.3, 1, 2.3) + m * (-0.5, 0.7, -0.5) = (x, 8, z)`

It's been a while since I've done any maths and I am not really sure if this is really even a Vector problem, I feel that I'm not even framing the question correctly, apologies!

Comment: you have $1+0.7m=8$

Comment: Ah! I see it now. I can solve for m and use that to solve for x and z. Thanks!